# 2 tabs - convert text in 1 tab acourding to text-id in second tab

Tags: excel

I have a list of in column A in tab 1 of many exact text values. In the second tab I have list of each exact text value (column A) and its Id number (on column B).

I would like to change all the text in tab A according in to their Id numbers.

I have over 500 Id numbers (so manually it will not work).

Comment: First of all ... what have you done so far to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Vlookup` in another column in tab1, let's say `Column B` like this:
Note: Assuming `Tab2` is the name of your sheet.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Tab2!A:B,2,0)
```

Then copy it all the way down up to where you have data.
Then copy all values in `Tab1 Column B` (the one you put your formula on) then Paste it as values in `Column A`.

This is just based on how you constructed your question.
Hope this helps.